# Copy snippet to answer doesn't really copy the code into the snippet

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

So I just noticed this, When I click on 'Copy snippet to answer' it does copy the code into the answer textarea box. However, it doesn't really copy the code inside the snippet itself. So if I were to click this  [image]    little guy to go into the Code Snippet window, the copied code wouldn't be there. Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the expected behaviour.

When you click *that little guy* (the toolbar button) [image], you are actually creating a **new** code snippet. If you look under the copied code snippet, you'll find *this little guy*:

[image: "edit the above snippet"]

Click that instead.